# VS Code Extension to Update Workspace Settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been combing through VS Code API docs, and am trying to understand whether or not it is actually feasible to write an extension that can edit the global User Settings JSON file.

Am I correct in thinking that I can create my extension, add the metadata I'm after under the "contributes" section in the "configuration" child object, then based on those values when the plugin is activated, take action against the User's preferences JSON?

I've also looked at the Guides plugin's configuration to check other examples, I'm just having a hard time conceptualizing how all this works, so any pointers would be appreciated.

I'm definitely NOT asking for someone to write my extension, just provide an answer as to whether I'm understanding the mechanics of an extension as a developer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would this work?

```
import { ConfigurationTarget, workspace } from 'vscode';

const configuration = workspace.getConfiguration(<YOUR_SECTION>);
configuration.update(<SETTING_NAME>, <SETTING_VALUE>, ConfigurationTarget.Global).then(() => {
    // take action here
});
```

More information about the `WorkspaceConfiguration` object located [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration).

Comment: Cheers @greenharbour. I managed to figure some things out after playing with the API, and yes, your suggestion is helpful, thank you

Comment: @trebleCode I have the same question you posted. Could you update your post with things you figured out?

Comment: @mingxiao based on my understanding at this point, you can create an event listener in TypeScript to handle this. There are some built in event types in TS for files but don't recall the name offhand.

Comment: @trebleCode thanks, I was able to achieve my desired goal
`const section = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('someSection'); const subsection = section.get('subsection');subsection["key"] = "value";`

Comment: Hi, what if my <SETTING_NAME> contains a Dot e.g. statusBar.Background, How should I update settings in that case.

Comment: @Ayu_Sh_Arma , You can chain `.get` after the initial getConfiguration, like: `workspace.getConfiguration('<first key>').get('<secound key>');`